# Typescript: extend a literal type to allow more options

Tags: typescript

So I have one type that contains a few possible literal values:

```
type ProductStatusType = 'INACTIVE' | 'ACTIVE' | 'UNKNOWN';
```

but I'd also need another type that will be exported and will have more options (including the above):

```
export type ExtendedProductStatusType = 'INACTIVE' | 'ACTIVE' | 'UNKNOWN' | 'NEW_STATUS' | 'ANOTHER_STATUS'
```

I know that to extend a type one can use the intersection (&) sign but I'm struggling how to make it just another literal option.

Incorrect meta code below:

```
export type ExtendedProductStatusType = ProductStatusType & { | 'NEW_STATUS' | 'ANOTHER_STATUS' }
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a union between the original union and the new literals:

```
type ProductStatusType = 'INACTIVE' | 'ACTIVE' | 'UNKNOWN';

// Same as 'INACTIVE' | 'ACTIVE' | 'UNKNOWN' | 'NEW_STATUS' | 'ANOTHER_STATUS'
export type ExtendedProductStatusType = ProductStatusType | 'NEW_STATUS' | 'ANOTHER_STATUS'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=92&pln=3&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwDKwCGwUDOAKuNALxQDkAkgHICCAwkdQGoCilUAPlUyxy69KAVVoBpWgHkA6rUoBuALAAoVRAAeYBHGBRQkKOw3AIAOyQQk8ZOiy58xUlAo3UGbHkIlDw2uxkAfUwieiIRTCE+aSIACXYAJWDQ8MigA)

Unions of unions are automatically flattened.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I was overthinking it